# BigQuery API:: Able to insert CSV data but data reflection in BigQuery is untimely

Tags: python, google-app-engine, csv, google-bigquery

Using python script for `Google app engine` to upload `CSV data` into `Bigquery`. Coded using `PyDev` perspective of `Eclipse on Windows 7`.

The `insert` is successful but inside BigQuery sometimes the data gets inserted immediately and sometimes it takes hours to reflect.

```
j={
'kind': 'bigquery#insertRequest',
'jobReference': {'projectId': '#######'},
'configuration': {
    'load': {

        'sourceFormat': 'CSV',
        'destinationTable': {'projectId': '############',
                             'tableId': '###########',
                             'datasetId': '##########'},

        'allowJaggedRows': True,

        'sourceUris': ['gs://bucket_naem/file_name'],
        'skipLeadingRows': 1,
        'schema': {'fields': [
                               {'type':'Data_Type','name':'Col1_name'},
                               {'type':'Data_Type','name':'Col2_name'}

                             ]
                   },
        },
    },
}


response = service.jobs().insert(projectId = "##########",body = j).execute()
```

Comment: do you have a job id for a job that took longer than you'd expect?

Answer (score 1):

A BigQuery load job is asynchronous, which is why it returns immediately. After the insert() call returns, it will give you a job id. You can then use that job id to look up the state of your job. Once that job completes successfully, your data should be immediately available.

If an import takes hours, that is unexpected (unless you are importing a massive amount of data); if that is the case, please provide a job id and we (BigQuery engineers) can look up what happened in the logs.

Comment: Thanks Jordan, your suggestions helped.                            Error was in schema definition in code.  Issue resolved now.

Comment: Is there any method in python or java, to insert csv/excel files from Google Drive to Bigquery directly? Keeping in mind that the data is formatted priorly according to Bigquery while storing in Drive.